# How to define 1000 dataframes in a single one?

Tags: r

My problem is the following. Suppose I have 1000 dataframes in R with the names `eq1.1`, `eq1.2`, ..., `eq1.1000`. I would like a single dataframe containing my 1000 dataframes. Normally, if I have only two dataframes, say `eq1.1` and `eq1.2` then I could define

```
df <- data.frame(eq1.1,eq1.2)
```

and I'm good. However, I can't follow this procedure because I have 1000 dataframes.

I was able to define a list containing the names of my 1000 dataframes using the code

```
names <- c()
for (i in 1:1000){names[i]<- paste0("eq1.",i)}
```

However, the elements of my list are recognized as strings and not as the dataframes that I previously defined.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where do these data frames come from in the first instance and why are they not in a list? To be explicit: *do not* generate separate data.frames. Generate a list of them and rbind/cbind/whatever them, afterwards.

Comment: `nam <- paste0("eq1.", 1:1000)`

Comment: Take a look at gregor's answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for reasons in storing data.frames in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
df.names <- ls(pattern = "^eq1\\.\\d")
eq1.dat <- do.call(cbind,
                   lapply(df.names,
                          get))
rm(list = df.names)
```

Comment: @CarlBoneri ... you say a tuber that varies in size and color that can be sliced and fried in oil or diced and mixed with dressing and eaten as a salad.

Comment: ..." it's naht a tuber"

Comment: Thanks! the function get() combined with lapply() did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
```

# recreate dummy data

```
lapply(1:1000,function(i){
      assign(sprintf("eq1.%s",i),
             as.data.frame(matrix(ncol = 12, nrow = 13, sample(1:15))),
             envir = .GlobalEnv)
    })
```

# Now have 1000 data frames in my working environment named eq1.[1:1000]

```
> str(ls(pattern = "eq1.\\d+"))
> chr [1:1000] "eq1.1" "eq1.10" "eq1.100" "eq1.1000" "eq1.101" "eq1.102" "eq1.103" ...
```

1) create a holding data frame from the ep1.1 data frame that will be appended
each iteration in the following loop

```
empty_df <- eq1.1
```

2) im going to search for all the data frame named  by convention and 
create a data frame from the returned characters which represent our data frame
objects, but are nothing more than a character string.

3) mutate that data frame to hold an indexing column so that I can order the data frames properly from 1:1000 as the character representation will not be in numeric order from the step above

4) Drop the indexing column once the data frame names are in proper sequence
and then unlist the `dfs` column back into a character sequence and slice
the first value out, since it is stored already to our empty_df

5) loop through that sequence and for each iteration globally assign and 
bind the preceding data frame into place. So for example on iteration 1, 
the empty_df is now the same as data.frame(ep1.1, ep1.2) and for the 
second iteration the empty_df is the same as data.frame(ep1.1, ep1.2, ep1.3)

#### NOTE: the `get` function takes the character representation and calls the data object from it. see ?get for details

```
lapply(
  data.frame(dfs = ls(pattern = 'eq1\\.\\d+'))%>% 
    mutate(nth = as.numeric(stri_extract_last_regex(dfs,'\\d+'))) %>%
    arrange(nth) %>% select(-nth) %>% slice(-1) %>% .$dfs, function(i){
      empty_df <<- data.frame(empty_df, get(i)) 
    }
)
```

All done, all the dataframes are bound to the empty_df and to check

```
 > dim(empty_df)
    [1]    13 12000
```